# Microsoft Access - Create a numerical sequence based on field value changes?

Tags: ms-access-2007, sequence

For query data like this:

```
   +-------+---------+ 
   | Name  | Details | 
   | JEFF  |  TEST1  |
   | JEFF  |  TEST2  |
   | JEFF  |  TEST3  |
   | BOB   |  TEST1  |
   | BOB   |  TEST2  |
   +-------+---------+
```

How do I query so that a numerical sequence (1,2,3...) can be added that resets back to 1 each time the name changes (ie from JEFF to BOB)?

Is it possible to use the DCOUNT function?

What I have so far is (it doesn't sequence correctly):

```
Number: (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  [dQuery] 
WHERE  [dQuery].[Name] =  [dQuery].[Name] 
AND  [dQuery].[sequence] >=  [dQuery].[sequence])
```

**UPDATE1:**

The correct query is:

```
SELECT [dQuery].Name, [dQuery].[sequence], (select count([dQuery].Name) + 1 
from [dQuery] as dupe where 
dupe.[sequence]< [dQuery].[sequence] and dupe.name  = [dQuery].name
) AS [Corrected Sequence]
FROM [dQuery]
WHERE ((([dQuery].Name)="jeff"))
ORDER BY [dQuery].Name, [dQuery].[sequence];
```

Comment: Why do you believe you need to do this?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - It is for a custom report - the sequence shows the step-by-step occurence of a number of activites and this sequence changes dynamically based on the source data.

Comment: Is the sequence that you're attempting to generate derived from other data? If so, why not use the data it's derived from to order the results? If that information is not stored anywhere, then perhaps the data model is not as complete as it ought to be.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - the data is from a tool that I have no control over.  And given how the data is structured requires this realtime sequence generation.  The joys of ultra-customized code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html).  I think the author has solved some very similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to add a serial number in your report dynamically than, create a report for the specific table and open the report in design view. Then, add a text box in the left side of the the data row and give "=1" (with out colon) to its Control Source property @ "Data" tab. And change "No" to "Over Group" of its "running sum" property @ "Data" tab. At the run time that text field will show data in sequence like 1, 2, 3 in every row.

Thanks